# How to encode/decode live audio in a single gstreamer pipeline?

Tags: gstreamer

For the sake of testing, I'd like to construct a pipeline that encodes and then decodes live audio. I have tried with mp3 or aac encoding, and I can certainly do it if the source is non-live:

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc ! lamemp3enc ! mpegaudioparse ! mad ! alsasink
$ gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc ! faac ! audio/mpeg, stream-format=raw ! aacparse ! faad ! alsasink
```

In the above cases, the pipeline is constructed and I can hear the audio playing back. However, if the source is live, the pipeline doesn't fail to play, but there's no audio played back.

I'm sure I'm missing some key concept, but can't see what!

Comment: Read this link: http://www.z25.org/static/_rd_/videostreaming_intro_plab/   .It will give fairly good idea how to create live streaming pipelines. I think most important thing in making these pipelines are taking care of packetization of packets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can it be the live source you are using causing the issue? It may have additional latency causing the audio sink to drop all samples.

How about this pipeline:

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc is-live=true ! faac ! aacparse ! faad ! autoaudiosink
```

Here the audiotestsrc acts as if it was a live source. Also note that it is advised to add parsers after encoder elements. So "aacparse" for AAC audio and "mpegaudioparse" for MP3 audio.

Comment: Right, forgot to put the audio parser in the question, although I was using it. And thanks for the answer, autoaudiosink picks pulsesink which works. I still don't understand why alsasink didn't work.

Comment: I'm on OS X so I could not use alsasink. If there is no other error on the pipleine maybe ALSA expects less latency as this pipeline can provide. You may want to try a "queue" element right before the sink and tinker with the "min-threshold-time" property of it. This way you might be able to hold enough data to feed to the alsasink at all times. Or there are additional prerolling options or something in the "alsasink" aswell.